# PHP add number beginning of variable

Tags: php

Greeting, need help to solve this problem.

```
$x = 5;
$y = 19;
$z = 100;
```

This number must be in 4 digit only.
Example if return 19 it must be 0019. How to added '0' in the beginning of variable.

```
output:
$x = 0005;
$y = 0019;
$z = 0100;
```

Comment: str_pad($value, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
$number = 19;
$val = str_pad($number, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $val;
// 0019
```

Comment: I don't like this answer, it's to obvious,. plus someone mentioned it in the comments... {sarcasm}.  No it's good I love `str_pad` works good for a line separator in CLI eg.  `echo str_pad('', 64, '=')` prints a line of 64 `========`

Answer (score 3):

Use sprintf :

```
sprintf('%04d', 15);
```

Alternatively you can also use str_pad:

```
str_pad($value, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: Nice, I always forget about `sprintf`.  I edited it to put it in code blocks easier to read...

Answer (score 1):

Use [str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
$x = 5;
$y = 19;
$z = 100;
echo str_pad($x, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)."<br>";
echo str_pad($y, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)."<br>";
echo str_pad($z, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Output

```
0005
0019
0100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
    $output  =  substr('0000'.$Input, -4);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = 5;
$y = 19;
$z = 100;
$x= "000".$x;  
$y= "000".$y;
$z= "000".$z;`
```

This form is simple or

```
<?php 
$number=12443;
$format = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
echo $format;
?>
```

Comment: You know if you do 4 spaces, it puts it in a bigger code block?  But you have to put text (without 4 spaces) after it, to break out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You guys took all the good answers

```
$x = 23;

while(strlen($x)<4)$x='0'.$x;

echo $x;
```

Outputs

```
0023
```

[Test it online!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3efc0faff05a28d66bcb6845786c56fa0380c44f)

Sorry this is all that was left.